# Корень слова "правильно"

Tags: морфемика, морфемный-разбор, корень-слова

Есть однокоренное слово "прав", но в учебнике написано, что корень "правиль".
Почему корень не "прав"?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Если это детский учебник, то, видимо, это объясняется тем, что ребенок не в состоянии понять, что правило — это то, что используется для (у)правления, а также неспособностью или нежеланием объяснить, что такое -иль, если корень прав-.

Если смотреть на вопрос «по-взрослому», то более верным будет, конечно, выделение корня прав-, который содержит глагол *править*. Правило — суффиксальное от него производное (ср. шить — шило, мыть — мыло, пугать — пугало и проч.), то есть -л- в середине слова — это суффикс. Прилагательное *правильный*, в свою очередь, образовано с помощью суффикса -н- (ср. ваниль — ванильный, запал — запальный и др.), а -л- смягчился, потому что в русском языке действует такое правило, когда перед суффиксом -н- некоторые согласные смягчаются (этому есть историческое объяснение).

Вот, собственно, и всё, а выделять корень правиль- при живых-то глаголах *править, исправить* преждевременно.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, потому что смотрите сколько слов: правильный, неправильный (прилагательные), правильно, неправильно (наречия), правильность, неправильность (существительные). Целое словарное гнездо! И значения мало совпадают со значением слов правый, право и т.д. Выходит, что возник новый корень "правиль", что и зафиксировано в словарях.

Comment: А как быть с глаголами _править, исправить_, прилагательным _правый_ («Я прав, а он нет!»)? Неужели они вообще теперь не связаны с правильностью?

Comment: С прилагательным "правый" совершенно ясно: значение другое. Не "вообще не связано", но всё-таки другое. Исправить – это да, это "сделать правильным".